# how to increment the variable correctly?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

when I start the timer ..timel is incremented normally ..but as soon as I stop the timer i.e. call the click_TimerStop function and start the timer again...the timel variable is incremented by timel+=2..and when I repeat the process ..it is increased by timel+=3..and it goes on and on ...how do I correct this ?..

```
DispatcherTimer clktimer =  new DispatcherTimer();

private void click_TimerStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)


{

    clktimer.Start();

    clktimer.Interval =new TimeSpan(0,0,1);

    clktimer.Tick +=clktimer_tick;

}

private int  timel = 0;

private void clktimer_tick(object sender, object e)
{

   timel++;
   timerSecond.Text = timel.ToString();

}

private void click_TimerStop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    clktimer.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
    clktimer.Tick -=clktimer_tick;
```

before

```
    clktimer.Tick +=clktimer_tick;
```

you'll unsubscribe and subscribe to event, so only one handler will be active at a time

and It's better to call `start()`  after you set all settings to timer

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're continually adding the `clktimer_tick` event handler each time you start the timer. Initialize your timer somewhere where it will only be called once and not every time you start, because there's no need to keep setting the same settings each time.